# How to print only if a character is an alphabet?

Tags: python, regex

This is from my previous post here:

[How to return 1 only if the last letter of a word is a vowel? Return 0 otherwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76070565/how-to-return-1-only-if-the-last-letter-of-a-word-is-a-vowel-return-0-otherwise/76071580#76071580)

Here is the code I am using:

```
import sys
import re

pattern = re.compile("^[a-z]+$")  # matches purely alphabetic words
starting_vowels = re.compile("(^[aeiouAEIOU])")  # matches starting vowels
ending_vowels = re.compile("[aeiouAEIOU]$")  # matches ending vowels
starting_vowel_match = 0
ending_vowel_match = 0

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()  # removes leading and trailing whitespace
    words = line.lower().split()  # splits the line into words and converts to lowercase
    for word in words:
        if len(word) == 1:
            print(word[0], 1, *((1, 1) if word[0] in 'aeiou' else (0, 0))) # * unpacks startVowel 1 endVowel 1 if word[0] is a vowel
        else:
            print(word[0], 1, 1 if word[0] in 'aeiou' else 0, 0) 
            print(*(f'{letter} 1 0 0' for letter in word[1: -1]), sep='\n')
            print(word[-1], 1, 0, 1 if word[-1] in 'aeiou' else 0)
```

I want this to only print if a character is an alphabet, so an example output I would like is this for a text file containing the string "It's a beautiful life":

```
i 1 1 0
t 1 0 0
s 1 0 0
a 1 1 1
b 1 0 0
e 1 0 0
a 1 0 0
u 1 0 0
t 1 0 0
i 1 0 0
f 1 0 0
u 1 0 0
l 1 0 0
l 1 0 0
i 1 0 0
f 1 0 0
e 1 0 1
```

I am currently seeing this:

```
i 1 1 0
' 1 0 0
t 1 0 0
s 1 0 0
a 1 1 1
b 1 0 0
e 1 0 0
a 1 0 0
u 1 0 0
t 1 0 0
i 1 0 0
f 1 0 0
u 1 0 0
l 1 0 0
l 1 0 0
i 1 0 0
f 1 0 0
e 1 0 1
```

I am wondering how to get rid of special characters in the output. I have tried a couple things including adding

```
        for letter in word:
            if pattern.match(letter):
```

in the `for letter in word"` block, but it is not returning the output I want.

Comment: You need to rewrite this: *print(*(f'{letter} 1 0 0' for letter in word[1: -1]), sep='\n')*

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why the original code does some work with *re* as it's never used.

When analysing a word of more than 1 letter, you need to consider all characters in the [1:-1] split individually.

Something like this:

```
import sys
from string import ascii_lowercase as LOWER

VOWELS = set('aeiou')

def isvowel(c):
    return int(c in VOWELS)

for line in sys.stdin:
    for word in line.strip().lower().split():
        if len(word) == 1:
            print(word, '1 1', isvowel(word[0]))
        else:
            print(word[0], 1, isvowel(word[0]), 0)
            for letter in word[1:-1]:
                if letter in LOWER:
                    print(f'{letter} 1 0 0')
            print(word[-1], '1 0', isvowel(word[-1]))
```

**Output:**

```
i 1 1 0
t 1 0 0
s 1 0 0
a 1 1 1
b 1 0 0
e 1 0 0
a 1 0 0
u 1 0 0
t 1 0 0
i 1 0 0
f 1 0 0
u 1 0 0
l 1 0 0
l 1 0 0
i 1 0 0
f 1 0 0
e 1 0 1
```

Comment: the original code had re because it was part some boilerplate code given to me for a mapreduce problem I am working on. It might be needed later.

Answer (score -1):

So you want to split a string into words and every word into alphabetical letters. For each letter you want wo print:

```
[letter] [starting_vowel_match] [letter_vowel_match] [ending_vowel_match]
```

Here would be my approach to this problem:

```
import re

test = "It's a beautiful life"

for line in test.split("\n"):
    line = line.strip()  # removes leading and trailing whitespace
    words = line.lower().split()  # splits the line into words and converts to lowercase
    for word in words:
        for letter in re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '', word):
            print(
                letter, 
                1 if word[0] in 'aeiou' else 0,
                1 if letter in 'aeiou' else 0, 
                1 if word[-1] in 'aeiou' else 0)
```

The result looks different than your example output but I expected the first row to contain  the starting_vowel_match!

```
i 1 1 0
t 1 0 0
s 1 0 0
a 1 1 1
b 0 0 0
e 0 1 0
a 0 1 0
u 0 1 0
t 0 0 0
i 0 1 0
f 0 0 0
u 0 1 0
l 0 0 0
l 0 0 1
i 0 1 1
f 0 0 1
e 0 1 1
```